# Launching an Intent outside an activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an asynch task with my app which goes to a website, grabs the results from the API and appends a number of clickable textviews to an existing LinearLayout.

However I want to be able to launch a new activity when the textview is clicked. This isn't possible with the asynch class defined in a seperate file, would it be easier to define it as an inline class within the activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always pass Context to your async class.

A better approach would be to have callbacks (listeners) in the calling class for the async to call back to.

Comment: This is probably the best solution to the problem. However I cheated a little and inlined the class within the activity.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to inflate your TextViews from an XML file that declares an onClick attribute, naming a method defined in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a context as an Activity! You will probably receive a cast error anyway. Instead, you can pass the activity as a function parameter, like this:

```
 public void function(Activity act)
 {
   Intent intent = new Intent(act, newActivity.class);
   act.startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Or overload the constructor to accept the activity as a parameter. But I strongly suggest you to check you code. If you are calling an activity, you, probably, should be within another one, don't you agree? But, I Know that sometimes we have to make a few concessions, in order to make things work properly. So, use it wisely.